# Override values.yaml in a dependency chart - MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have a requirements.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  - name: mongodb-replicaset
    # Can be found with "helm search <chart>"
    version: 3.13.0
    # This is the binaries repository, as documented in the GitHub repo
    repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

And i want to modify the values.yaml file of the mongodb-replicaset chart , espacialy this section:

```
auth:

  enabled: false
  existingKeySecret: ""
  existingAdminSecret: ""
  existingMetricsSecret: ""
  # adminUser: username
  # adminPassword: password
  # metricsUser: metrics
  # metricsPassword: password
  # key: keycontent
```

How can i override the values.yaml file on initialization in a dependency chart?

Answer (score 3):

You put the values under a key matching the name of the upstream chart so

```
mongodb-replicaset:
  auth:
    enabled: true
    etc etc
```

Comment: Im new to helm, where exactly should i put those values? Inside my own values.yaml file? Also how can i avoid writing username and password to a file?

Comment: You would usually put the static, non-secret parts in the umbrella chart's values.yml. Secret values would be passed in at runtime using the `-f` command line flag, but managing secret values with Helm is very tricky and you should read up on the ramifications and plugins that can help. Personally I don't recommend it, which is one of the (many) reasons I don't recommend Helm.

Answer (score -1):

I would say workflow can be next:

1) download everything locally using [helm dependency update](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#chart-dependencies) - When helm dependency update retrieves charts, it will store them as chart archives in the charts/ directory.

Example from official documentation

```
$ helm dep up foochart
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "local" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "example" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "another" chart repository
Update Complete.
Saving 2 charts
Downloading apache from repo http://example.com/charts
Downloading mysql from repo http://another.example.com/charts
```

2) change values.yaml under mongodb-replicaset chart as was suggested by @coderanger

3)deploy helm chart using local  downloded|\modified files

Another option is to check is: parent values.yaml charts config file.
As per [Subcharts and Global Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/):

> -A subchart is considered “stand-alone”, which means a subchart can never explicitly depend on its parent chart.
>
> -For that reason, a subchart cannot access the values of its parent.
>
> -A parent chart can override values for subcharts.
>
> -Helm has a concept of global values that can be accessed by all charts.

Please look into "Overriding Values from a Parent Chart" section of [Subcharts and Global Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) documentation - it has an example how to override subcharts values using global one.

Hope it helps